# Enviar imagenes a telegram por web

Tags: php, web, telegram

Tengo este codigo para poder enviar texto y e imagenes a telegram via web, pero el problema que las imagenes no me las envia a traves del inputfile aqui abajo dejo el codigo..

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0);
 
$token = "AQUI API";
 
$chat_id = "CHAT ID";
 
$photo = "$_POST[photo]";
 
$text = "$_POST[text]";
 

$response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=$text");

$response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendPhoto?chat_id=".$chat_id."&photo=".$photo."&caption=".$caption);
 
?>

<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>
            <span>chat_id :</span>
            <input id="chat_id" type="text" name="chat_id" value="" />
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>caption :</span>
            <input id="text" type="text" name="text"/>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>photo</span>
            <input id="photo" type="file" name="photo" />
        </label>      
         <label>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="sendPhoto" />
        </label>    
    </form>
```

a ver si alguien me podria ayudar

gracias antemano!

Comment: los archivos no van en $_POST. Lo puedes recojer en $_FILE[photo]... Puede ser eso?

Comment: Si adapta esto , le puede servir: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35030243/8933039

Comment: Nada, no funciona

Comment: Puede ser buena idea cambiar de navegador desde donde estas probando y asegurate que `php.ini` te permite subir archivos.

Answer (score 0):

Con el api de fatherbot de telegram puedes hacerlo así:

```
curl -X  POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot"<TOKEN>"/sendPhoto" -F chat_id="<ID>" -F photo="<RUTA DE LA IMAGEN EN INTERNET>"
```

Si quieres usar una ruta relativa:

```
curl -X  POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot"<TOKEN>"/sendPhoto" -F chat_id="<ID>" -F photo="<@RUTA DE LA IMAGEN EN INTERNET>"
```

y para adjuntar texto junto con la imagen (esta va de gratis):

```
curl -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot"<TOKEN>"/sendPhoto" -F chatid"<ID>" -F caption"<TEXTO JUNTO IMAGEN>" -F photo="@<RUTA DE NUESTRA IMAGEN>"
```